# How to make server-side paging in datatable?

Tags: javascript, ajax, data-paging

I am using MVC. I have large amount of data and I need to have data only with paging limit. For example, if page size is 10 I want to get only top 10 records in my database.

Here is my html :

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="data_table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
    <th> Anket Id  </th>
    <th> Anket Adı </th>
    <th> Katılımcı </th>
    <th> Soru      </th>
    <th> Aktif Gün </th>
    <th> Dil       </th>
    <th> Durum     </th>
    <th> Kayıt Tarihi </th>            
</table>
```

And here is my JS :

```
 var table =  $('#data_table').DataTable({

            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajaxSource": "/Survey/ActiveSurveysPaging",
            "dataSrc": "",
            "aoColumns": [
                { "mDataProp": "Anket Id" },
                { "mDataProp": "Anket Adı" },
                { "mDataProp": "Katılımcı" },
                { "mDataProp": "Soru" },
                { "mDataProp": "Aktif Gün" },
                { "mDataProp": "Dil" },
                { "mDataProp": "Durum" },
                { "mDataProp": "Kayıt Tarihi"}
            ],
       ..........
```

and this is what my server returns as json :

```
 {"sEcho": 3,"iTotalRecords" : 1013,"iTotalDisplayRecords" : 1013,"aaData" :   [["56523938aa9c580dac1858e5","anket-0","1001","8","11","TR","Aktif","22.11.2015 23:52"],

["5652393aaa9c580dac185918","anket-1","1000","8","11","TR","Aktif","22.11.2015 23:52"]]}
```

When I run the program it gives "can not read propert lenght of undefined" error while it is loading datatable. Where I am doing wrong and thanks for any solution please.

Comment: what technologies do you use? What is the DataTable function? What is the server-side code like?

Comment: DataTable function is well-know bootstarpt-dataTable and my server-side code is like this :   [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult ActiveSurveysPaging(int iDisplayStart, int                         iDisplayLength){..... return jsonObject }

Answer (score 0):

try something like [JqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html)
If you want to implement your own table with pagination, Do same like Jqgrid

Comment: Hello, I could not  see the pagination part in this link can you help me to find it?

Comment: [server side pagination](http://call-me-early.blogspot.in/2012/02/jqgrid-server-side-paging-implement.html) find here